# Swift custom operators with Unicode combining characters

Tags: swift, unicode, operator-overloading, diacritics

**TL;DR**
 Can I coax the compiler to accept a combining character as a postfix operator?

The references at [Swift.org](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/LexicalStructure.html) and [GitHub](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/8802d6d52afcac225e9d460e3441c88f4e52b8f2/include/swift/AST/Identifier.h#L87-L121) and this [useful gist](https://gist.github.com/natecook1000/c5fb2b8cd0967f53770e) suggest that combining characters (e.g. U+0300 ff.) may serve as operators in Swift.

With judicious implementation (omitted here) I can say “Fiat Lux” and there is

```
prefix  operator ‖      // Find the norm.
postfix operator ‖      // Does nothing.
func             /      // Scalar division.
```

which allows

```
let vHat = v / ‖v‖      // Readable as math.
```

or even

```
let v̂ = v / ‖v‖        // Loving it.
```

The OCD in me wants now to use the combining circumflex as a (topfix) operator like this:

```
let normalizedV = v̂  // Combining char is really a postfix.
```

So I leap in and try to write:

```
postfix operator ^      // Want this to be *combining* circumflex.
postfix func ^(v: Vector) -> Vector { v / ‖v‖ }
```

and can do it with plain old U+005E circumflex, but get (various) compiler errors when I try with the combining circumflex U+0302.

[image]

Comment: U+0302 is an allowed “operator-character” but not an “operator-head”, i.e. not the first character of an operator

Comment: Aargh! You are right. I *read* `operator-head → U+3008–U+3020` but I *saw* U+0302.

Comment: You can answer this and I'll mark it correct. Even if the mystery was just my bad vision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An operator name (or any other identifier) cannot start with the `U+0302` character. Like all combining marks, it is an allowed “operator-character” but not an allowed “operator-head”. From [Lexical Structure > Operators](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/LexicalStructure.html#ID418) in “The Swift Programming Language”:

> GRAMMAR OF OPERATORS
>   operator → operator-head operator-characters<sub>opt</sub>
>   ...
>   operator-character → U+0300–U+036F